# CakePHP 3.7 - Set view variable from inside custom authentication class

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, custom-authentication

I am writing my own authentication class for a stateless REST API. To make usage for developers easier I would like to return specific error messages when authentication fails, ideally by just a view variable. However, I haven't figured out how the authenticate class can access the view variables.

*How can I set view variables from authentication? Or how can I work around this?*

To give some idea:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

class HmacAuthenticate extends BasicAuthenticate
{

    // ...

    public function getUser(ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request->getEnv('PHP_AUTH_USER');
        $hash = $request->getEnv('PHP_AUTH_PW');
        $timestamp = $request->getEnv('HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION_TIMESTAMP');

        if (!is_string($user_id) || $user_id === '' || !is_string($hash) || $hash === '' || !is_string($timestamp) || $timestamp === '')
        {
            $this->set('authError', 'Missing essential fields');

            return false;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to do this with flash messages (which are saved in the session) than with view variables?

Comment: But the Flash comonent isn't available either. And that won't work for serialized views.

Comment: No time for a proper answer... authentication objects don't know about views, and it should stay that way, their only concern is authentication. Throw an exception and catch it in a custom/extended auth component if required. Also check out the new [**authentication plugin**](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication), which supports returning result objects with custom codes and messages to evaluate elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can set view variables inside the login action itself, in the Controller you specified in the Authentication config, eg:

```
 $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => 'Users'
    ],
```

For this configuration, in the `UsersController`'s `login` action, you presumably have something like this, where you can set view variables and serialize them:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            // For example:
            $user_id = $this->request->getEnv('PHP_AUTH_USER');
            $hash = $request->getEnv('PHP_AUTH_PW');
            $timestamp = $request->getEnv('HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION_TIMESTAMP');

            if (!is_string($user_id) || $user_id === '' || !is_string($hash) || $hash === '' || !is_string($timestamp) || $timestamp === '')
            {
               $this->set('authError', 'Missing essential fields');
            }
        }
    }

    $this->set('_serialize', true);
}
```

Comment: So basically repeat the validation step by the authenticator in the controller. That doesn't seem very DRY.